# Does parallel flink tasks affect each other if they are unioned at the end?

Tags: apache-flink

I have the following task in flink. it seems that A is getting back-pressured although there isn't busy task in his own dataflow but in parallel one, which joins later.
Is it possible A is back-pressured because of B? it might be related to watermarks alignment maybe?

EDIT: image from flink UI

[image]